# Does renewal process always has independent increments?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

We all know that poisson process has independent increments. It is also a renewal process for the sequence of exponential random variables. However the question is:

> Let $( X_t, t \ge 0) $ be a renewal process for the sequence $\{ \xi_n\: | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ iid random variables. Does $X_t$ have independent increments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_t$ needn't have independent increments. Let $\xi_1$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{P}(\xi_1 = 1) = \mathbb{P}(\xi_1 = \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$ and let $X_t$ be the corresponding renewal process. That is $$X_t = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{\{\sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j \leq t \}}$$ 
Then $X_{1/2} - X_0$ and $X_{5/4} - X_{3/4}$ clearly aren't independent since $X_{1/2} - X_0 = 0$ implies $X_{5/4}-X_{3/4} \geq 1$ so $$\mathbb{P}(\{X_{5/4} - X_{3/4} = 0 \} \cap \{X_{1/2} - X_0 = 0 \}) = 0 \neq \mathbb{P}(X_{5/4} - X_{3/4} = 0)\mathbb{P}(X_{1/2} - X_{0} = 0)$$